# User login with Passport js and mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, passport.js

I've seen this question asked already, sorry if it seems repetitive; but I've read through a lot of the answers and they haven't helped. I keep getting a "MISSING CREDENTIALS" error no matter what I do with the login form. I'm trying to implement a user login using email and password.

My Route File

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const User = require('../models/user');

passport.use(new LocalStrategy((email, password, done) => {
  User.getUserByEmail(email, (err, user) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    if(!user) {
      return done(null, false, {message: 'this account does not exist'});
    }

    User.comparePassword(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
      if(err) throw err;
      if(isMatch) {
        return done(null, user);
      }
      else {
        return done(null, false, {message: 'oops! wrong password! try again'});
      }
    });
  });
}));

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.getUserById(id, (err, user) => {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/toSignInPage',
    failureFlash: true
  })(req, res, next);
});

module.exports = router;
```

user.js file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    trim: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  profilePhoto: {
    originalemail: String,
    imagePath: String
  },
  token: String
});

const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports.registerUser = function(newUser, callback) {
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      newUser.password = hash;
      newUser.save(callback);
    });
  });
};

module.exports.getUserByEmail = function(email, callback) {
  const query = {
    email: email
  };
  User.findOne(query, callback);
};

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback) {
  User.findById(id, callback);
};

module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback) {
  bcrypt.compare( candidatePassword, hash, (err, isMatch) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    callback(null, isMatch);
  });
};
```

I've initialized passport in my app.js file - session options and all that nice stuff.

also my html(handlebars)for the form

```
       <form method="post" action="/signInPage">


          <label for="mail"> Email </label>
          <input type="email" id="mail" name="email" />
          <label for="password"> Password</label>
          <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>

          <button type="submit">Sign in</button>

          <p class="corp"> <a href="forgot.html">Forgot password?</a> </p>

        </form>
```

Any help is appreciated on this. I've been stuck for a while debugging and I can't seem to figure out what I must have done wrong. please if I didn't properly format the question in an understandable format let me know.

Comment: I don't see the post action for the form on the server. Am I missing it? As a side note, you really should not respond to the user in a way that's different if the user isn't found vs the user is found but has an incorrect password, makes hacking easier.

Comment: thanks very much for the reply. The post action is actually '/signup' the route being defined in a folder called signup.js. Thanks also for the side note I'll be sure to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

Someone who I'm grateful to posted a link to the solution; but I can't find the comment, so I'll just add the solution.

Passport js logs user in with user name by default

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy((username, password, done) => {

}));
```

so I was trying to use email

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy((email, password, done) => {

}));
```

in order to log a user in with email, I had to do it this way

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy((email, password, done) => {
  {
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password'
}
}));
```

this will override the default use of username to email...

here's the link to the soultion:

https://github.com/scotch-io/easy-node-authentication/blob/master/config/passport.js#L58